# how to print out json data from csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

```
[{"Name": "Luke Skywalker", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Darth Vader", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": "TO THE REPUBLIC, TO DEMOCRACY!"}, {"Name": "Anakin Skywalker", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Yoda", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Palpatine", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Qui-Gon Jinn", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Jar Jar Binks", "Affiliation": "N/A", "Allegiance": "Possible Sith"}, {"Name": "Darth Maul", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Mace Windu", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Ki-Adi-Mundi", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Kit Fisto", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Eeth Koth", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Plo Koon", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Dooku", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}]
```

the output im getting above is what im getting with the code:

```
    data = []
    with open('starwrs.csv') as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f):
            data.append(row)

    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return json_data
```

but how do i get it so that it looks like actual json data like directly under eachother etc and not the string that im getting

```
[{"Name": "Luke Skywalker", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, 
{"Name": "Darth Vader", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)...

```
import json
json_data='[{"Name": "Luke Skywalker", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Darth Vader", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": "TO THE REPUBLIC, TO DEMOCRACY!"}, {"Name": "Anakin Skywalker", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Yoda", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Palpatine", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Qui-Gon Jinn", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Jar Jar Binks", "Affiliation": "N/A", "Allegiance": "Possible Sith"}, {"Name": "Darth Maul", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Mace Windu", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Ki-Adi-Mundi", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Kit Fisto", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Eeth Koth", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Plo Koon", "Affiliation": "Jedi", "Allegiance": ""}, {"Name": "Dooku", "Affiliation": "Sith", "Allegiance": ""}]'
json_object = json.loads(json_data)
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)
print(json_formatted_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to pretty print the json. If that's the case use this

```py
json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(json_data)
```

The indent in json.dumps helps to create the indentation which makes json look formatted

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "Luke Skywalker",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Darth Vader",
        "Affiliation": "Sith",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": "TO THE REPUBLIC, TO DEMOCRACY!"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Anakin Skywalker",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Yoda",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Palpatine",
        "Affiliation": "Sith",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Qui-Gon Jinn",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jar Jar Binks",
        "Affiliation": "N/A",
        "Allegiance": "Possible Sith"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Darth Maul",
        "Affiliation": "Sith",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Mace Windu",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ki-Adi-Mundi",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Kit Fisto",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Eeth Koth",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Plo Koon",
        "Affiliation": "Jedi",
        "Allegiance": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "Dooku",
        "Affiliation": "Sith",
        "Allegiance": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: hi thank you for your reply! but when i do this change it doesnt change what im doing in python because im running it right now by using python flask

Comment: the data will be stored in string format and indentation will not be there. It's only when its being printed that indentation will be seen.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: so im reading a csv file at the moment and when i do the code above it prints it out like a string and for some reason the python flask only seems to let me print it out like that despite trying your indent tip, like local host says this "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list", is it because of python flask that I can't indent it properly? I'm reviewing it on the web browser

Comment: or is there a way if I could do it by having data as a dict?

Comment: since you are reviewing in the web browser, Javascript needs to handle it. Try the following JSON.stringify(json_data, undefined, 4)

Comment: If the answer helped you please upvote and accept the answer